# Why does adding a str number to itself turn it into a number?

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion, numbers

There's nothing on MDN js documentation that gives an idea as to why the following happens.

```js
var numAsStr = "2"
numAsStr = +numAsStr
console.log(typeof(numAsStr)) //outputs Number
```

[string gets turned into a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxnGN.jpg)

Comment: you can reproduce the problem if you change second line to `numasStr=+numAsStr`!

Answer (score 1):

This is because unary will convert string if it is already in form of an integer.Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) on "Unary plus (+)" section

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding a string number to itself, you're applying the "+" operator to a string and capturing the coerced value. If you instead write it as

```
var numAsString = "2"
numAsString += numAsString
console.log(typeof numAsString)
```

You'll see that it doesn't coerce to a number. The same behavior will happen if you write it as

```
numAsString = -numAsString
```

Answer (score 0):

its telling you what type of character is inside the string. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof